# Аванса или авансом?

Tags: выбор-слов

В предложении: 
миллиард аванса или авансом?

Comment: Ни "миллиард аванса", ни "миллиард авансом" не являются законченными предложениями. Приведите пример целиком.

Answer (score 2):

Даже "**миллиард авансов**" не должен пугать (если рассматривать это словосочетание в аспекте глобальной статистики авансовых выплат).
Оба выражения корректны, но различаются по употреблению.

**Миллиард аванса** = миллиард денежных единиц, формально предусмотренный как "аванс" (сумма, выплачиваемая до завершения работы по договору). Здесь акцент на *статусе* платежа: деньги выплачиваются *в качестве* оговоренного аванса (ср. *тысяча рублей штрафа*).

> Налогобложению подлежат полученные вами **миллиард аванса** и два
>   миллиарда прочих поступлений.

**Миллиард авансом** = миллиард денежных единиц, *передаваемый* в качестве предварительного платежа. "Авансом" здесь относится не к самому миллиарду, а к способу его выплаты: этот миллиард, **выплачиваемый авансом** - акцент на *действие* с миллиардом.

> Всего за работу мы заплатим вам три миллиарда, из них в среду готовы
>   выплатить **миллиард авансом**.

Можно и первый пример переформулировать в этом аспекте, хотя порядок слов изменится (полученный *авансом миллиард*):

> Налогобложению подлежат **полученный** вами **авансом** миллиард и два
>   миллиарда прочих поступлений.

Answer (score 0):

"Миллиард аванса" и тому подобные прецеденты, скорее всего, появились в речи из-за измененного употребления самого слова "аванс" в разговорной речи. С французского avance переводится как "задаток", "опережение". То есть мы можем сказать "аванс (читай: задаток) в миллиард". Но в русском языке более корректным является употребление "**миллиард авансом** (читай: задатком)", а не "миллиард аванса".